# Android Gradle detect is a release build or not in runtime?

Tags: android, gradle

I need to create auto-increment version mechanism via Gradle. For this I use [this](http://devdeeds.com/auto-increment-build-number-using-gradle-in-android/) manual and create two files

## version.properties

```
#Fri May 20 11:04:03 EEST 2016
VERSION_BUILD=3
```

## build.gradle at app level:

```
buildTypes {

        debug{
            versionNameSuffix 'debug';
        }
        release {
            def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

            if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
                def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
                versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
                def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
                versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
                versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

                versionNameSuffix = versionBuild;

            } else {
                throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
            }
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
```

The my problem is : `VERSION_BUILD` increments each time when I build project. Not a `Run`, just a build. And don't matter I Run project or create a signed APK.

The my goal - increment version only when I generate signed APK. How I can do that?

Comment: can't you just move the code that increments VERSION_BUILD in the specific variant? am I missing something ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I don't know. I'm not familiar with gradle so far.

Comment: you could try (have tried - before posting as well)

Comment: @Blackbelt even If I move this code to specific flavor( I have three for different processor types) - how I can detect that this is a task for generate Signed APK?

Comment: my bad, I meant variant but I wrote flavor.

Comment: @Blackbelt no changes. VERSION_BUILD increments after each build run.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found solution.

```
List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();

for (String item : runTasks) {
    if (item.contains("assemble") && item.contains("Release")) {
           // this is a release task
    }
}
```

Comment: This does in my case not seem to differ between a "build and run" and "build APK" - did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

From your gradle file,everytime you run a rel build you sign the app. 
So Why not use versionCode instead of VERSION_BUILD, that way it will only happen when you build.